# Javascript Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var myArray = ['burak', 'mirhan', new Date(), 'ibrahim'];


for (var i = 0; i <= myArray[i].toString ().length; i++) {
    alert (myArray [i].toString ().length); 
}
```

ı wrote the code above. it works. but firebug alerts that "myArray[i] is not defined". I can't solve it. Can you help me on this ? As you can understand I am little bit noob on javascript. I am trying to learn so thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4):

When you iterate over an array, you should be simply be looking at the length of the *array*, not the length of the string in the current element of the array:

```
for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++)
```

Comment: Maybe an explanation why the OP's code doesn't work and how this is different and why it works? I don't want to steal your thunder :)

Answer (score 2):

```
var myArray = ['burak', 'mirhan', new Date(), 'ibrahim'];


for (var i = 0, len = myArray.length; i < len; i++) {
    console.log(myArray[i]);
};
```

If you are a JS efficienado:)

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript, array indices start at `0`, and an array's `.length` property will be one higher than the current highest element index. So for your array with four contiguous elements the `.length` will be 4 and the element indices are 0, 1, 2 and 3.

You need to set up your loop to run from `0` to `.length - 1`, so use `i < myArray.length` rather than `i <= myArray[i].toString ().length`:

```
for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++)
```

The reason you though your code was working other than that error is that because you had `i <= myArray[i].toString ().length` it was testing `i` against the length of the `toString()` values of elements in the array rather than against the length of the array itself. So on the first iteration when `i` was 0 it would test if 0 is less than or equal to the length of the first element in the array, on the second iteration it tests if `i` is less than the length of the second element, and so forth. Because all items in your array had a `.toString().length` greater than the length of the array itself your loop did iterate through all of the elements, but then when `i` got to `4` it tried to test an element that didn't exist.

Comment: +1 for `an array's .length property will be one higher than the current highest element index`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to loop over each item in the array, you need to get the array length:

```
var myArray = ['burak', 'mirhan', new Date(), 'ibrahim'];


for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    alert (myArray [i].toString ().length); 
}
```

Comment: Note that `<` is needed rather than `<=`.